# how to highlight the div using slideToggle()?

Tags: jquery

How can I highlight the div if it is visibile?

```
$('#add_dom').click(function(){
  $('#new_dom').slideToggle("slow");      
  return false;
});
```

Comment: What do you mean by "highlight"? Apply some CSS class? jQuery UI highlight?

Comment: You can highlight it in any case: if it's not visible, no one will know :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After your slide ends, this function will check if it is visible and add or remove a class of highlight.

```
$('#add_dom').click(function(){
  $('#new_dom').slideToggle("slow",function(){
    $(this).is(':visible') ? $(this).addClass('highlight') : $(this).removeClass('highlight');
  });      
  return false;
});
```

Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$('#new_dom').effect("highlight", {}, 3000);
```